# Insert loop result into data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a for loop which prints a result, just a single number and an i(for 1:10)

```
(count <- (length(which(colSums(data2[, -8])==0))))
print(i)
```

When I run all parts of the loop manually it prints the correct count(decreasing in value). And I could manually put all the values in excel to plot. However, Id like in my loop for count and i to be added to a new data frame, so I can run this a thousand times to get a reliable result.

And get a dataframe like this:

```
i   count
1   10
2   9
3   8
4   6
5   4
6   4
7   4
8   3
9   2
10  0
```

So my question basically is: how do I extract 'count' and 'i' and create a dataframe to fit this in(make a row for each i).

Datasets and the rest of the loop is irrelevant for the solution I think.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers Jasper

## EDIT

My current loop

```
for(i in 1:10) {

data2 <- data2[-sample(nrow(data2),size=1,replace=FALSE),]
(count <- (length(which(colSums(data2[, -8])==0))))
print(i)

}
```

Comment: `count` is a single number, independent of `i` in the code you've written...?

Comment: Count is indeed  a single number, independent of i. 

> (count <- (length(which(colSums(data2[, -8])==0))))
[1] 9

Comment: i is like time, it samples 10 times random rows and calculates the amount of columns with 0. There are 10 different samples, so its always dead after 10 tries.

Comment: I think you'll need to actually write your loop for this to make sense. I think you have some `data` and within the loop create `data2 <- data[sample(1:nrow(data),10),]`, but I can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient approach would be to compute the column sums first and difference for each sample:

```
cs <- colSums(data2[,-8])

nsim   <- 10
res    <- vector("integer",nsim)
for (i in 1:nsim) res[i] = sum(!(cs - data2[sample(1:nrow(data2),1),-8]))

simres <- data.frame(i=1:nsim,res=res)
```

Note that `length(which(x))` is the same as `sum(x)` here; and `x==0` is `!x`.

---

*Comments.* It might also be a good idea to store your data in a `matrix` if it is all numeric and operations like this are frequent.

There are many alternatives to `for` loops in R. Here's an example typical for simulations:

```
res <- replicate(nsim,sum(!(cs - data2[sample(1:nrow(data2),1),-8])))
```

If you're taking many samples, you could also precompute the row-left-out value for every row:

```
norowres <- rowSums(!(cs-data2[,-8])) # not tested
res      <- sample(norowres,nsim,replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: Don't subset a data.frame in a `for` loop. It's more efficient to fill a vector and put it into a data.frame after the loop.

Comment: @Roland Good to know; I'll switch to that.

Comment: Thanks, simres <- data.frame(i=1:nsim) was what I was looking for.